# Generate new listile per day in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Add new tiles to a builder as a result of a new day.... today is march 23, and the builder contains 23 tiles by tomorrow which is march 24, tiles should be 24 tiles..pls help me out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of the day in the month like so:

```
int dayNumber = DateTime.now().day;
```

If it's the 24th march this dayNumber will be 24. Then you simply build dayNumber listTiles.

Comment: Thanks so much, how about based on the number of days in a year....today being march 25, tiles should be 85 tomorrow 86....thanks

Comment: Simply always add 60: `int dayNumber = DateTime.now().day + 60;`